# SQL Using Chinese Letters in Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, encoding, sqlplus

I've been searching a lot this week but I haven't yet found a solution. Thanks for your help in advance!

I am trying to automate a SQL Query via running it as batch file over sqlplus in Windows cmd. I am quite limited to this tool as sql cl is not supported at the company I work for. Overall sqlplus works fine - it reads in the query and gives output EXCEPT it obviously skips the part with Chinese letters.

In SQL Developer the whole query works.

The purpose is to return the number of elements that are located at a highway, so part of the statement is to search in the addr_street field for highway/autobahn/...:

```
AND ((addr_street Like '%Autobahn%'            
   OR addr_street Like '%Autovia%'            
   OR addr_street Like '%Autopista%'          
   OR addr_street Like '%Interstate%'        
   OR addr_street Like '%Highway%'
   OR addr_street Like '%Autostrada%'
   OR addr_street Like '%公路%'
```

.....

How can I rewrite the part with the Chinese letters as ASCII Code so that sqlplus on the cmd is able to read the file in?

I tried to use the unistr function - the query in SQL Developer did not return an error but does not return any additional result at several tries with different input.

```
AND ((addr_street Like '%Autobahn%'            
   OR addr_street Like '%Autovia%'            
   OR addr_street Like '%Autopista%'          
   OR addr_street Like '%Interstate%'        
   OR addr_street Like '%Highway%'
   OR addr_street Like '%Autostrada%'
   OR addr_street Like unistr('\0631\06CC\062D\0627\00B7\00AF')
```

**So my question is simple:**

How can I rewrite

```
OR addr_street Like '%公路%'
```

to NOT use the Chinese symbols and get the same result? Would you use another tool/approach than sqlplus?

Comment: do u need to convert it or insert this value ?

Comment: Hi @Andrew. First of all thanks for your fast reply. I want the query to return a sum of all elements that have '%Highway%' somewhere in their name field.

Comment: It works fine in mysql 8, but give it a try and see what happens

Comment: Hello @nbk but how can I write it as concatenated string? So when I use just unistr(XYZ) it probably just returns "1" if the first letter of the field is equal to the ASCII hex code. But I want it to return "1" if the letter is anywhere in the field. So something like '%' + unistr(XYZ) + '%' ... but all combinations I tried did not work in SQL

Comment: please make an example of your data in dbfiddle. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Did you put the `%` code first and last in the unistr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unistr seems to work here, let's use `asciistr` at first:

```
select asciistr(n'公路') from dual   --> result:  \516C\8DEF
```

and use these values in query:

```
with t(addr_street) as (select 'x公路q' from dual)
select * from t where addr_street like '%' || unistr('\516C\8DEF') || '%'
```

Row found.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes, rather than double quotes, to create a text literal and for a `NVARCHAR2/NCHAR` text literal you need to prefix it with `N`

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value NVARCHAR2(20) );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (N'玄真');
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name

select asciistr(N'玄真') from table_name --this is optional if you already insert value with 'N'
```

Result

```
| VALUE |
|-------|
|    玄真 |
```